# SQL return the last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i need to return the last date after 11 months this date enter in my sql.
But if i have the same name i should return this name with the most recently date

Ex

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 03/17/21 |
| Max | 02/19/21 |
| John | 02/19/21 |

My code:

```
select * 
from TAB_ATESTADO_DE_SAUDE_OCUPACIONAL 
where datediff (month, DATE, '02/17/2022') >= 11
```

And return this for me

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 03/17/21 |
| Max | 02/19/21 |
| John | 02/19/21 |

I need to return this:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 03/17/21 |
| Max | 02/19/21 |

Comment: What does this mean:  "i need to return the last date after 11 months this date enter in my sql"?  And what does the rest of the question have to do with 11 months?

Comment: I work in a factory and I need to make a system that returns those who need to do a series of medical exams after 11 months he already did, in the first year ok, but after 2 years the names will be repeated and I need to filter by the most recent date that employee did these exams.
Sorry for the bad English, I haven't been talking for a long time

Comment: In my table i haave the name of all exams, and i need to list them too, do you prefer that i show the whole table ?

Comment: It seems you want one row per name but your sample data is likely too simplistic to understand what logic you desire. If there are 3 (or more!) rows that "match" for John, which one is expected in the output? Also - use a date format that is not subject to interpretation problems - suggest you use YYYYMMDD as the format.

Comment: My output need to be the most recent date if jhon did the exams in the following dates - 03/17/2019 and 03/17/2020 my output need to be 03/17/2020

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to combine filtering with aggregation?

```
select name, max(date)
from TAB_ATESTADO_DE_SAUDE_OCUPACIONAL
where datediff(month, DATE, '2022-02-17') >= 11
group by name;
```

Note:  I would recommend writing the `where` clause as:

```
where date <= dateadd(month, -11, '2022-02-17')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
select name, max(date) as 'Last Date' 
from TAB_ATESTADO_DE_SAUDE_OCUPACIONAL
group by name
having DATEDIFF(month,max(LoadedDate),GETDATE()) >= 11
```

For each name you are displaying the latest date, at than at end you are filtering only the records where the difference between the max(date) and now is higher than 11.